# error by installing wordpresswith duplicator

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, xampp

i want to immagriate a a website from a server to another using Duplicator pro. We i open Installer.php i get this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: decoct(): Argument #1 ($num)  must be of type int, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php:713 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php(713): decoct('u+rwx') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php(689): DUPX_Bootstrap->setPermsOnItem('dup-installer', 'u+rwx') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php(672): DUPX_Bootstrap->setPerms('dup-installer', 'u+rwx', false) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php(598): DUPX_Bootstrap->fixInstallerPerms('http://localhos...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php(1788): DUPX_Bootstrap->run() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\installer.php on line 713
```

i tried to install in another computer, it works normally! Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, because my source system is a Debian Linux server on PHP 7.3.19 and target system was a Windows 10 with XAMPP on PHP 8.0.0.
After downgrading to XAMPP with PHP 7.4.13 the installation worked as expected.
BR
Tilmann

Comment: Thank you! It works now, but i dont understand the problm wioth php 8.0.0